# Laravel nova on action show page to get data from various field from user

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-nova

I have one resource (`User` table) for which I need to perform some action.

However when that action selected I want to pass too many additional fields and selection is dynamic.

For example, if I select any `user` and click on action then in action I should select a `category` from DB and based on that `category` I need to get `subcategory` and based on that `subcategory` I want to get some seller on action page in Nova...

Is there any way i can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Action Fields` might help you with that.  You can add additional nova fields to your collection of models before handling them in the action.

Hope that this can help: [nova action fields](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/actions/defining-actions.html#action-fields)

Comment: i know about action field but it's not have a dynamic field selection

Answer (score 0):

you can use this great NovaPackage

https://github.com/epartment/nova-dependency-container